# Что за пауза перед началом работы гугл скрипта

Tags: google-apps-script, триггер

В последнее время гугл скрипт после запуска скрипта будь то по триггеру или из редактора сначала делает какую то паузу в несколько минут и только потом начинает работу. Я для этого дела специально первой командой поставил Logger.log("Поехали") чтобы видеть время начала работы в логах, и там иногда сразу начинает работать, а иногда висит минуты 3. И это пауза жрет лимит времени на выполнение скрипта, не понимаю что это пауза, и как с ней бороться. У кого нибудь было такое?

```
function everyday() {
  Logger.log("Поехали! Получаем вчерашнюю дату");
...
}
```

[image: Вот тут видно что скрипт три минуты ничего не делал]

Comment: `everyday` - это весь код? Попробуйте временно переключиться на другой аккаунт. Если это не весь код, то хотелось бы посмотреть, что там еще есть.

Comment: конечно это не весь код, просто я подумал что дальнейший код не влияет на то что скрипт так долго думает перед тем как запуститься. У меня есть подозрение что это из-за очень тяжелой таблицы с которой я взаимодействую в скрипте, попробую поменять на новую чистую таблицу и проверить это

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело было в том что таблица с которой работал скрипт имела большие габариты, была одна вкладка на которой было 300к строк и 3 столбца, никаких явных ошибок это не давало, но скрипт как я и писал в вопросе просто мог подолгу висеть ничего не делая. Как только я избавился от этой вкладки (раскидал на куски по отдельным таблицам) эта аномалия исчезла